# simple_form collection and &nbsp in name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have selection to chose categories for board.

```
<%= simple_form_for @board do |f|%>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <% unless @board.root? %>
    <%= f.input :parent_id, collection: formated_collection(@board), include_blank: false %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Helper method:

```
  def formated_collection(board)
    if board.new_record? 
      out = board.root.subtree
    else
      out = board.root.subtree - board.subtree
    end

    out.map {|b| b.name = "#{"&nbsp;"*b.depth}#{b.name}";b}
  end
```

In the form I have selection list, it should look like this:

```
Root Name
  Cat1
    Cat2
  Cat3
```

Instead of it I get :

```
Root Name
&nbsp;Cat1
&nbsp;&nbsp;Cat2
&nbsp;Cat3
```

Any idea why it doesnt change this into non-breaking space?

Answer (score 1):

I fix it, but this html_safe makes me confused all the time :(.

In helper:

```
out.map {|b| b.name = "#{"&nbsp;"*b.depth}#{b.name}";b}
```

Should be:

```
out.map {|b| b.name = "#{"&nbsp;"*b.depth}#{b.name}".html_safe;b}
```

Comment: If you don't use html_safe, rails will assume that the string should be displayed as text as is, i.e. don't interpret any of the string as html.